# facebook open graph image not displaying and og:image and og:title

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far as I can tell the og tags on my site are correctly configured, but when sharing a post in Facebook, other images are appearing. photo appear but it take photo caches. When you look in source in there are no image . only in that page

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mtcit.am%2Fpages.php%3Flang%3D1%26id%3D63%26page_name%3Djobs
you can chek here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mtcit.am%2Fpages.php%3Flang%3D1%26id%3D3904%26page_name%3Dhratap

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. _“As far as I can tell”_ - great, and what are we supposed to do with _that_ kind of information? _We_ have no way of telling whether anything is correct or not, if you don’t show us _anything_. Have you at least used the Facebook debug tool and checked what that has to say?

Comment: Give us the URL you're sharing, and try running it through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what Facebook's parsing.

Comment: i add the link and meta